# GDB hangs on GNU Fortran stack frame

Tags: c++, gcc, gdb, fortran

I have a large, mixed C++ and Fortran code base that I'm trying to debug.

The program is built with GCC and GNU Fortran version 4.8.  The Fortran code is built with `-c -g -cpp -ffixed-line-length-none -ffree-line-length-none -fcoarray=single -fno-underscoring -fPIC` and the C++ code is built with `-g -Wall -Wno-reorder -Wno-parentheses -std=c++11 -Wno-unknown-pragmas -fPIC`.  The program is linked with `g++ -g ... -lgfortran`.

When I run the program in GDB, I can set a break point in the Fortran code using `break my_func.f90:35`.  However, when the program hits that breakpoint, the debugger appears to go into an infinite loop trying to print out the stack trace.  If I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> at this point, I get a truncated stack trace, like this:

```
^CBreakpoint 2, my_func (accinfile=Quit
(gdb)
```

So the program has hit the breakpoint, it seems something is going wrong with the stack trace.  If it breaks in C++ code but with a Fortran function in the stack trace, I get the stack trace up to the Fortran part, but again a hang at that point.

I've confirmed that GDB works with a very simple C++/Fortran program.

Has anyone come across this behaviour?  Is there a known solution?

Comment: That sounds like a GDB bug. Maybe you should [report it](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/enter_bug.cgi?product=gdb)?

Comment: Certainly an option.  I'd like to be able to reproduce it in a test case first, though!